# symfony2: how to use group_concat in QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having nested-set (using Gedmo tree) entity called "Location". Entity "Appartment" has location_id and what I need to do it to map scalar value called eg "path" to query that returns all appartments.

In Doctrine1, I had this code:

```
/**
* Add "path" to each element
* 
* @param Doctrine_Query $query
* @param string $separator
*/
protected function addScalar_path(Doctrine_Query $query, $separator=", ")
{
    $subquery = "k99.root_id=o.root_id AND k99.lft<=o.lft AND k99.rgt>=o.rgt AND k99.level<=o.level" ;

    $query->addSelect("(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(k99.name ORDER BY k99.level SEPARATOR '$separator') FROM Location k99 WHERE $subquery) AS path") ;
}
```

Note: "o" alias is used for primary query.
This code would allow me to use

```
{foreach .... as $appartment}
   {$appartment->path}
...
```

Which would print:

```
Australia, Victoria, Melbourne, ...other children...
```

How to do the same thing in D2? And how to even include doctrine extenstions in my symfony2 project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [symfony2: Using group\_concat in QueryBuilder(Doctrine)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401082/symfony2-using-group-concat-in-querybuilderdoctrine)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want to use it in QueryBuilder you must :

1) add DQL functions GroupConcat:  [GroupConcat](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/src/Query/Mysql/GroupConcat.php)

2 ) Registering GroupConcat :[DQL User Defined Functions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html)

another alternative is to use NativeQuery :[Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)

---

In symfony2 registering a function DQL it's very simple just add GROUP_CONCAT in config.yml  like:

```
    entity_managers:
        default:
            dql:
                string_functions:
                    GROUP_CONCAT: YourBundle\Query\Mysql\GroupConcat
```

For more information visit [Registering Custom DQL Functions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html)

Comment: +1 for Native SQL. Aside from that is a bit heavy for inexperienced Doctriners that is still the best solution...

Comment: I am VERY experienced Doctrine1 user but D2 is killing me. Is there some example code for what I need? I aslo need QB instead of NativeQuery. And how do I even register GroupConcat in Symfony2 project?

Comment: See above I added the way to register Group_Concat in Symfony2 but for Native Query you can view the official example,

Comment: I tried what you said about the NativeSql mode, I've already used this method before but now the same query that works directly in phpmyadmin, returns an empty array from doctrine Native SQL query... 

SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM     Products
GROUP BY category, line, type

Comment: Solution of adding GroupConcat and Registering worked like a charm. If you are using ORM (default stuff), the config.yml goes as follow: doctrine > orm > dql > string_functions > GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: @a.aitboudad do you have any idea how to use DQL functions in doctrine2 partials ?

Comment: "Native SQL" link is not working anymore (permission denied)

Answer (score 29):

If any comes across this post, there's now a [Doctrine Extensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) repository in Github. The repo has instructions on how to use it. You can use composer to install it and then use any function you're interested in.

**EDIT:**

For the Sake of the user Tushar, the way to use GROUP_CONCAT in Doctrine2's DQL is simple install [Doctrine Extensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions):

```
composer require beberlei/DoctrineExtensions
```

To enable it: add the following in your config.yml:

```
doctrine:
 orm:
     dql:
         string_functions:
             group_concat: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\GroupConcat
```

Then in your code, you should be able now to use Group Concat in your DQLs:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('location')
            ->select('location')
            ->addSelect("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT location.name SEPARATOR '; ') AS locationNames");

        $result = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Or in the case for the original question:

```
$query->addSelect("(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(k99.name ORDER BY k99.level SEPARATOR '$separator') FROM Location k99 WHERE $subquery) AS path");
```

Answer (score 5):

Just an addition to @a.aitboudad's answer: 
 The DQL function GroupConcat linked appears to have a «limited support for GROUP_CONCAT». 
Here is the full support version : 
The configuration is as he mentioned.

```
// -------------------------------------------------
// Complete support of GROUP_CONCAT in Doctrine2
// -------------------------------------------------
// Original Article: http://habrahabr.ru/post/181666/
// Automated translation to English: http://sysmagazine.com/posts/181666/ 
// Original github commit: https://github.com/denisvmedia/DoctrineExtensions/blob/d1caf21cd7c71cc557e60c26e9bf25323a194dd1/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/GroupConcat.php

/**
 * DoctrineExtensions Mysql Function Pack
 *
 * LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the new BSD license that is bundled
 * with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to kontakt@beberlei.de so I can send you a copy immediately.
 */

namespace DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode,
    Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

/**
 * Full support for:
 *
 * GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
 *              [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
 *                  [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
 *              [SEPARATOR str_val])
 *
 */
class GroupConcat extends FunctionNode
{
    public $isDistinct = false;
    public $pathExp = null;
    public $separator = null;
    public $orderBy = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $lexer = $parser->getLexer();
        if ($lexer->isNextToken(Lexer::T_DISTINCT)) {
            $parser->match(Lexer::T_DISTINCT);

            $this->isDistinct = true;
        }

        // first Path Expression is mandatory
        $this->pathExp = array();
        $this->pathExp[] = $parser->SingleValuedPathExpression();

        while ($lexer->isNextToken(Lexer::T_COMMA)) {
            $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
            $this->pathExp[] = $parser->StringPrimary();
        }

        if ($lexer->isNextToken(Lexer::T_ORDER)) {
            $this->orderBy = $parser->OrderByClause();
        }

        if ($lexer->isNextToken(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER)) {
            if (strtolower($lexer->lookahead['value']) !== 'separator') {
                $parser->syntaxError('separator');
            }
            $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);

            $this->separator = $parser->StringPrimary();
        }

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        $result = 'GROUP_CONCAT(' . ($this->isDistinct ? 'DISTINCT ' : '');

        $fields = array();
        foreach ($this->pathExp as $pathExp) {
            $fields[] = $pathExp->dispatch($sqlWalker);
        }

        $result .= sprintf('%s', implode(', ', $fields));

        if ($this->orderBy) {
            $result .= ' ' . $sqlWalker->walkOrderByClause($this->orderBy);
        }

        if ($this->separator) {
            $result .= ' SEPARATOR ' . $sqlWalker->walkStringPrimary($this->separator);
        }

        $result .= ')';

        return $result;
    }

}

// -------------------------------------------------
// Example of usage:
// -------------------------------------------------
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select("
            c as company,
            GroupConcat(b.id, ';', b.headOffice, ';', b.city, ';', s.name
            ORDER by b.id
            SEPARATOR '|') AS branches
        ")->leftJoin('c.branches', 'b')
    ->leftJoin('b.country', 's')
    ->groupBy('c.id')
    ->setFirstResult(0)
    ->setMaxResults(10)
    ->getQuery();
$result = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: this is the most horrible way to use mysql functions in query. why doctrine2 has restricted to use mysql functions directly.

Comment: They stole this function that I wrote myself, please change the credit to this one: http://habrahabr.ru/post/181666/ (sysmagazine.com seems to have done the automated translation of my article).

Comment: @StepanYudin : It's actually mentioned on the 2nd line : "Original Article: http://habrahabr.ru/post/181666/"

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. GROUP_CONCAT does not allow using CASE-WHEN inside.
[This library](https://github.com/oroinc/doctrine-extensions) fixed my issues, so maybe it will be helpful.