# How to group this table column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have a following data below:

**Table:**

```
Name    Number
Sam     1
Sam     2
Sam     3
John    4
Lani    5
Mera    6
```

Now I want as a result like this format below

**Result:**

```
Name    Number
Sam     1,2,3
John    4
Lani    5
Mera    6
```

How can I possibly do this? What I must going to use?

Comment: A simple PHP loop will suffice - I don't know doctrine, but I imagine something similar can be achieved with iterate().

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `group_concat()`:

```
select name, group_concat(number order by number) as numbers
from t
group by name;
```

Comment: I got this error:[Syntax Error] line 0, col 282: Error: Expected known function, got 'group_concat'

Comment: @hit.it That's a Doctrine issue, it doesn't know the MySQL functions by default. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883616/how-can-i-use-date-in-doctrine-2-dql

Comment: Here's a better link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401082/symfony2-using-group-concat-in-querybuilderdoctrine