# Platform dependent functions

Tags: php, doctrine

I need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` function in my DQL.

Solution is to add custom function: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31401082/2110496), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10850345/2110496)

But I need also to run my code on PostgreSQL database, so I need to implement `STRING_AGG` function too.

My question is:

How to implement `DQL` function(like `JOIN_STR(expr ',')`), rendered into `GROUP_CONCAT` on `MySQL` and into `STRING_AGG` on `PostgreSQL`?

In other words: what is correct way to determine current `Platform` from inside `FunctionNode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I found it via `SqlWalker::getConnection`:

```
  public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
  {
    $platform = $sqlWalker->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
    switch ($platform->getName()) {
       case 'mysql': //...
    }
    // ... 
  }
```