# Symfony Doctrine query - get a list of children for each parent

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

What I'm currently trying to do is create a query that returns a result with parent names and a **list** of child names.

For example, say we have two tables `Category` and `Product`, where `Category` has many `Product` entities. I understand that I can directly access the children using `getProducts()`, or if I didn't have an association setup using shared IDs and joins. However, it's at this point I'm unsure how to proceed, in essence, I want a result that looks like this:

```
| Category.name | Product.name |
| Cars          | BMW, Volvo, Fiat
| Bikes         | BMX, Mountain Bike, Road Bike
```

I think the SQL term I'm looking for is [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php), but that doesn't appear to be in [doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850345/symfony2-how-to-use-group-concat-in-querybuilder). So before I go marching off attempting to install an extension I don't really understand, I'd like to know if there is a simpler solution using Doctrine and the default query builder?

**Update:**

Using @Wilt's answer, I extended it slightly to produce the exact table above:

```
$qm = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qm->select('c', 'p')
   ->from('AppBundle:OmicsExperimentTypeStrings', 'c')
   ->leftJoin('c.omicsExperimentSubTypeStrings', 'p');
// Get query result as array for easier manipulation.
$results = $qm->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

$res = [];

// Iterate array structure and get c.name and an array of p.name.
foreach($results as $category) {
    $res[$category['name']] = [];
    foreach([$category['products']] as $productsArray) {
        foreach ($productsArray as $product) {
            array_push($res[$category['name']],$product['name']);
        }
    }
}

return $res;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use fetch joins for your case.
 Check the Doctrine documentation on fetch join here in [chapter **14.2.2. Joins**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins).

In a query builder you do fetch join like this:

```
$queryBuilder->select('c', 'p')
   ->from('Module\Entity\Category', 'c')
   ->leftJoin('c.products', 'p');
$results = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Now `$results` holds a collection of categories where each category has its product collection populated.

---

### UPDATE

I would say it would be better to get the objects and create the array from the objects in the view (or whereever you need it). 
If you really want to get only the fields you can change the select clause to select the fields you want instead. Not sure if the resulting array is exactly what you want but you can try it:

```
$queryBuilder->select('c.name', 'p.name')
    ->from('Module\Entity\Category', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('c.products', 'p');
$results = $queryBuilder->getResult();
```

Now results holds an array with the fields you selected.

Comment: Actually turns out I'm having a little bit more trouble than I thought, would you be able to update your answer so that it's only selecting `Category.name` and `Product.name`? I tried modifying it myself, but I've so far been unsuccessful.

Comment: What I did was edit the query after running it using `getArrayResult()`, but I imagine I can also do it directly in the query itself?

Comment: @Darkstarone I added an update. I hope it returns the array you are aiming for (I didn't test it)...

Comment: That second query returns an array where each entry is a single `p.name` wrapped in it's own array. Thanks for trying, I can use my work-around fine!