# How to save row order which is pointed in "IN()" expression?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a array of entity IDs - my task is fetch that entities in the order which is pointed in the array. I have found that combination of "IN()" and "FIND_IN_SET" can solve that task.

I built a query in repository class with the help of `QueryBuilder`:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('v');
$qb
    ->select('v')
    ->addSelect("FIND_IN_SET('v.id', '$vehiclesStr')")
    ->andWhere('v.id IN(:vehicles)')
    ->setParameter('vehicles', $vehiclesArr)
;

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

As you see, I use "FIND_IN_SET" function from [beberlei/DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions). It was registered accordingly to that [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850345/symfony2-how-to-use-group-concat-in-querybuilder#answer-10852752).

Suppose `$vehiclesStr = '219,197,213,198';` and respectively 
`$vehiclesArr = [219,197,213,198];`

**The problem** - order is not saving. I receive following result, where vehicles are ordered by ASC e.g. 197, 198, 213..:

[image]

**UPDATE / built SQL by Doctrine:**

```
SELECT 
  v0_.vehicle_id AS vehicle_id_0, 
  v0_.number AS number_1, 
  v0_.cargo_movers AS cargo_movers_2, 
  v0_.vat AS vat_3, 
  v0_.bargain AS bargain_4, 
  v0_.cargo_search_radius AS cargo_search_radius_5, 
  v0_.adr AS adr_6, 
  v0_.tir AS tir_7, 
  v0_.passing_cargo AS passing_cargo_8, 
  v0_.description AS description_9, 
  v0_.created_at AS created_at_10, 
  v0_.updated_at AS updated_at_11, 
  v0_.transport_service_id AS transport_service_id_12, 
  v0_.vehicle_photo_id AS vehicle_photo_id_13, 
  v0_.vehicle_driver_id AS vehicle_driver_id_14, 
  v0_.vehicle_type_id AS vehicle_type_id_15, 
  v0_.vehicle_body_size_id AS vehicle_body_size_id_16, 
  v0_.vehicle_full_size_id AS vehicle_full_size_id_17, 
  v0_.vehicle_show_to_cargo_sender_id AS vehicle_show_to_cargo_sender_id_18, 
  v0_.vehicle_body_equipment_id AS vehicle_body_equipment_id_19, 
  v0_.vehicle_loading_type_id AS vehicle_loading_type_id_20, 
  v0_.vehicle_price_around_town_id AS vehicle_price_around_town_id_21, 
  v0_.vehicle_price_out_of_town_id AS vehicle_price_out_of_town_id_22 
FROM 
  vehicle v0_ 
WHERE 
  v0_.vehicle_id IN (?) 
ORDER BY 
  FIND_IN_SET('v.id', '219,188') ASC 

Parameters: [[219, 188]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `ORDER BY` clause at all. Putting additional field in `SELECT` clause won't change order.WHy would it?

Try to use `orderBy` instead of `addSelect`.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('v');
$qb
    ->select('v')
    ->andWhere('v.id IN(:vehicles)')
    ->setParameter('vehicles', $vehiclesArr)
    ->orderBy("FIND_IN_SET(v.id, '$vehiclesStr')", 'ASC');
;

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Assuming `$vehiclesStr` has correct value of course.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I even listed IDs directly like this: "setParameter('vehicles', [219, 188])
orderBy("FIND_IN_SET('v.id', '219, 188')", 'ASC');" But it all the same doesn't save listed order.  May be better sort entities in PHP?

Comment: I have never seen FIND_IN_SET before but the docs indicate it works on strings, not integers which I assume your id's are.  Might try messing with straight sql just to see of you can get things to work.  Otherwise, do it in php and rethink your requirements.  Ordering by primary keys is a bit unusual.

Comment: @Molarro as I said, *assuming `$vehiclesStr` has correct value*. You shouldn't have spaces after commas. Try with `"FIND_IN_SET('v.id', '219,188')"`

Comment: @Jakub Matczak result haven't changed.

Comment: Could you provide final SQL query built by Doctrine? You can find them in Symfony's profiler.

Comment: @Molarro I've edited my answer. I've copied incorrect code from your example. It should be `FIND_IN_SET(v.id, '$vehiclesStr')`- no single quotes around `v.id`