# Error: Expected known function, got 'GROUP_CONCAT'

Tags: php, sql, symfony, symfony4

In PhpMyAdmin I can use the following script and it works like charm:

```sql
SELECT personal.city, GROUP_CONCAT(technologies.tech)
FROM personal
INNER JOIN technologies ON technologies.uid = personal.uid
WHERE personal.uid = 88
```

But I have a dynamic method, which looks like this:

```php
public function user($uid, $selection, $tables) {
    // 1. Query builder
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')->select($selection)->where('u.uid = :uid')->addSelect('GROUP_CONCAT(t.tech)');

    // 2. Get each table
    foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
        $queryBuilder = $queryBuilder->innerJoin('App\Entity\\' . $value, $key)->andWhere("$key.uid = :uid");
    }

    // 3. Finish and return the query
    return $queryBuilder
        ->setParameter('uid', $uid)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

If I run it, I'll get the following error message:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 25: Error: Expected known function, got
>   'GROUP_CONCAT'

What exactly am I doing wrong with `GROUP_CONCAT`?

The answers of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850345/symfony2-how-to-use-group-concat-in-querybuilder) did not help me, since they question refers to Symfony2 but I am using Symfony4.

Comment: Are we talking about symfony4? At previous versions you needed to add a doctrine. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850345/symfony2-how-to-use-group-concat-in-querybuilder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [symfony2: how to use group\_concat in QueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850345/symfony2-how-to-use-group-concat-in-querybuilder)

Comment: @freeek  The question is tagged with `symfony4`, so I would think that's the version being used here.

Comment: @freeek yes, I am using Symfony4.

Comment: @PatrickQ you are right, just wanted to be sure tag here not to get more attention.

Comment: Did you already register the function with your ORM? in your `doctrine.yaml` file?

Answer (score 2):

GROUP_CONCAT is not DQL function. You can`t use MySQL functions in DQL.
Here is a list of functions that Doctrine supports in DQL:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions

**I strongly advise you not to use GROUP_CONCAT in your app. You can fetch data as array in a separate query and concatenate it in PHP. There should be not noticeable performance overhead.**

But if you really have to use it you must write your own user defined DQL function.
Here is tutorial for it:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

And here is how you register that DQL function inside Symfony:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't find a better (or an easier solution), I am just passing a raw SQL with the following method:

```php
public function rawSQL($sql) {
    $statement = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing that issue after a lot of research I installed package "beberlei/doctrineextensions" and then into my doctrine config file i.e. doctrine.yaml in my case I added the following code and I'm able to use Mysql GroupConcat from the above package

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    dql:
        string_functions:
            GROUP_CONCAT: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\GroupConcat
```

**Note:** I'm also able to use other numberic MySQL functions like DEGREES, ACOS, SIN, RADIANS and COS through "beberlei/doctrineextensions"