# Doctrine JOIN with subquery in DQL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT
s.id,
e.exception,
s.name,
w.url,
w.web_id,
w.active,
w.suspended,
r.email,
p.name as partner,
p.id as partnerId,
group_concat(c.name) names,
group_concat(c.email) emails,
group_concat(c.tel) tels
FROM
service s
JOIN web w ON s.web_id = w.id
JOIN rus r ON w.rus_id = r.id
JOIN partner p ON r.partner_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN exception e ON e.service_id = s.id
JOIN contact c ON c.partner_id = c.id
where c.main = 1 or c.important = 1
group by s.id
```

and when I tried to convert it to DQL

```
$result = $this->_em
    ->createQuery(
        'SELECT s.name, w.webId, r.email, p.name as PartnerName
         FROM App\Model\Database\Entity\Service s
         JOIN App\Model\Database\Entity\Web w WITH s.web = w.id
         JOIN App\Model\Database\Entity\Rus r WITH w.rus = r.id
         JOIN App\Model\Database\Entity\Partner p WITH r.partner = p.id
         LEFT JOIN App\Model\Database\Entity\Exception e WITH e.service = s.id
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT
         p.id,
         group_concat(c.name) names,
         group_concat(c.tel) tels,
         group_concat(c.email) emails
         FROM
         App\Model\Database\Entity\Partner p
         LEFT JOIN App\Model\Database\Entity\Contact c WITH c.partner = p.id
         where c.main = 1 or c.important = 1
         group by p.id) test
         WHERE test.id = p.id'
    )->getResult();

return new ArrayCollection($result);
```

I'm getting:

`[Semantical Error] line 0, col 452 near 'JOIN (SELECT\r\n ': Error: Subquery is not supported here`

Using QueryBuilder is same..

Is there any hack to use left join with subquery either in DQL or using QueryBuilder?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you will need a subquery for this when you can handle it with join and aggregation. Like in the main query join your `contact` entity and perform aggregation for your desired result set. I have updated the group by clause and added all non-aggregated columns that are in the select clause so that this query will be valid even if MySQL's strict mode is enabled see [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and it will eliminate duplicate rows also as per the grouping criteria

In SQL it will be like

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.name,
    e.exception,
    w.url,
    w.web_id,
    w.active,
    w.suspended,
    r.email,
    p.name as partnerName,
    p.id as partnerId,
    group_concat(c.name) names,
    group_concat(c.email) emails,
    group_concat(c.tel) tels
FROM service s
    left join exception e ON e.service_id = s.id
    join web w ON s.web_id = w.id
    join rus r ON w.rus_id = r.id
    join partner p ON r.partner_id = p.id
    join contact c ON c.partner_id = c.id 
WHERE c.main = 1 or c.important = 1
GROUP BY s.id,
        s.name,
        e.exception,
        w.url,
        w.web_id,
        w.active,
        w.suspended,
        r.email,
        p.name,
        p.id
```

I believe you will need to add an extension to support Mysql's GROUP_CONCAT function in doctrine by default this is not included in doctrine orm.

To add support for [GROUP_CONCAT in doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36504208) you can follow the steps mentioned in the linked answer. Once it's registered you can transform your raw SQL to DQL as

```
SELECT  s.id,
        s.name,
        e.exception,
        w.url,
        w.web_id,
        w.active,
        w.suspended,
        r.email,
        p.id as partnerId,
        p.name as partnerName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) contactNames,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.email) contactEmails,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.tel) contactTels
FROM App\Model\Database\Entity\Service s
    LEFT JOIN App\Model\Database\Entity\Exception e WITH e.service = s.id
    JOIN App\Model\Database\Entity\Web w WITH s.web = w.id
    JOIN App\Model\Database\Entity\Rus r WITH w.rus = r.id
    JOIN App\Model\Database\Entity\Partner p WITH r.partner = p.id
    JOIN App\Model\Database\Entity\Contact c WITH c.partner = p.id
WHERE c.main = 1 or c.important = 1
GROUP BY s.id,
        s.name,
        e.exception,
        w.url,
        w.web_id,
        w.active,
        w.suspended,
        r.email,
        p.name,
        p.id
```

Or another approach will be to use [`ResultSetMapping`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/native-sql.html#examples) class of doctrine in which you can execute your raw SQL and map the result on the respective entities

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('App\Model\Database\Entity\Service', 's');
$rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'name', 'name');
$rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('App\Model\Database\Entity\Exception' , 'e', 's', 'exception');
$rsm->addFieldResult('e', 'exception', 'exception');
//.... other relations
$rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('App\Model\Database\Entity\Partner' , 'p', 'r', 'partner');
$rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'partnerName', 'name');
$rsm->addScalarResult('contactNames', 'contactNames');
// ... and so on

$sql = 'SELECT s.id, e.exception ... FROM service s JOIN ... WHERE ... GROUP BY s.id, e.exception ...';
$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$data = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Oh, I solved it same way as you described like a 4 days ago.
Will give you bounty anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

As answered in [#3542](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/3542)

> DQL is about querying objects. Supporting subselects in the FROM
> clause means that the DQL parser is not able to build the result set
> mapping anymore (as the fields returned by the subquery may not match
> the object anymore).

Your best bet would be to use sql instead

```
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$sql = 'Your query';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(); //Bind what parameters you need
```

Comment: Yeah I tried to use raw SQL but it's forcing me to rewrite giant chunk which is already ready for QueryBuilder.. Next thing I was thinking about is creating View and joining it.. but I'm not sure about Views in Doctrine..

Comment: A view might be a good idea. Have you already seen & tried this: https://robbert.rocks/aggregate-your-data-by-using-sql-views-and-doctrine